# Search Hashed Password File Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, hash

**THIS IS A SCHOOL ASSIGNMENT, NOT FOR PERSONAL GAIN**

I am creating a script that searches through a file filled with passwords for it's hashed equivalent. The file itself is plain text passwords, I am using a loop to convert to md5, and then search for, and match a value which I have pre-set "testmd5".

The problem I'm having is, it keeps returning "Not Found". The hashed value is within the text file so I'm guessing I am not correctly converting the plain text to hash within the file!

```
import hashlib
testmd5 = "a90f4589534f75e93dbccd20329ed946"

def makemd5(key_string):
    new_keystring=key_string.encode('utf-8')
    return (hashlib.md5( new_keystring ).hexdigest())

def findmd5(makemd5):
    found = False
    with open("passwords.txt", "rt") as in_file:
       text = in_file.readline()
    for text in ("passwords.txt"):
        if makemd5(text) == testmd5:
            print(text)
            found = True
    if found == False:
        print("Not Found")

def main():
    findmd5(makemd5)

main()
```

Any help regarding the would be appreciated!

This is the method I just learned to read files.

```
with open("test.txt", "rt") as in_file:
    while True:
        text = in_file.readline()
        if not text:
           break
        print(text)
```

Comment: I think you need to take a second look at how to read files.

Comment: Check question.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit your question with the new code.

Comment: What is `for text in ("passwords.txt")` supposed to do?

Comment: I was under the assumption that line would create the variable for reading the "text" within the file

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually searching the file, you're searching the string `"passwords.txt"`. You also miss the brackets from the function call to `readline`, which I think should be `readlines()` so that you can iterate the list of lines:

```
import hashlib
testmd5 = "a90f4589534f75e93dbccd20329ed946"

def makemd5(key_string):
    new_keystring=key_string.encode("utf-8")
    return (hashlib.md5( new_keystring ).hexdigest())

def findmd5():
    found = False
    with open("passwords.txt", "rt") as in_file:
       full_text = in_file.readlines()
    for text in full_text:
        if makemd5(text) == testmd5:
            print(text)
            found = True
    if found == False:
        print("Not Found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    findmd5()
```

It also seems unnecessary to pass the `makemd5` function around, so I've removed that.

Be consistent with quotes, you had used single for `'utf-8'`, but double quotes everywhere else.

Comment: I was missing the `.readline()`. Are you suggesting removing the `main()` and replacing it with the last line of code you have?  I have not seen that used before

Comment: `readline()` will only read one line, you may find you get better performance reading all of the lines with `readlines()` and iterating the list.

Comment: @JamesPi Yes, it's the best way to write a main function in python, it allows you to use the same code as a module if you need to. Anything within the `__name__=="__main__"` block is only run if the script is invoked "normally", it doesn't get evaluated if it's imported into another python script.

Comment: This seems right, but I am still getting `"Not Found"`. Do you think it has anything to do with the loop not getting one password per line when searching? I was told that might be an issue.

Comment: @JamesPi That's hard to say without seeing the file, s it possible to add an extract to the question?